# Read inner attribute/tags in RSS Items

Tags: c#, xml, rss, feed

I've try to read Rss Feed from multiple website, but some of this exposes your service (RSS) in a strange way, like this samples :

```
<item>

    <title>"2012 Minutos a Nadar" em Guimarães</title>
  <link>http://www.rtp.pt/noticias/index.php?article=534537&amp;tm=3&amp;layout=123&amp;visual=61</link>
    <description>
    <![CDATA[
 <img src="http://img0.rtp.pt/icm/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=/noticias/images/40/4031dece9b6d9384a6a021244cb0a36d&amp;w=620&amp;sx=0&amp;sy=10&amp;sw=560&amp;sh=307&amp;q=75&w=115"/> 
Esta noite as piscinas municipais de Guimarães não vão encerrar. Vão ser 2012 minutos a nadar 
sem paragens nem interrupções. Começou às 9 e meia da manhã e segue até ao final de domingo
Um encontro desportivo no âmbito da Capital Europeia da Cultura. A ideia passa pela festa da natação com cada um a nadar o que puder num máximo de 200 metros. As inscrições estão permanentemente a decorrer.

]]>
</description>

<guid>http://www.rtp.pt/noticias/index.php?article=534537&amp;tm=3&amp;layout=123&amp;visual=61</guid>

<author>online@rtp.pt</author>
<category>Desporto</category>
<category>Cultura</category>
<category>País</category>
<pubDate>Sat, 10 Mar 2012 16:42:02</pubDate>
</item>
```

It's possible for me get the 'img' on the descritpiton tag?! Or exclude this atribute from the descrition tag!?!?

Or in this sample :

```
<description><![CDATA[<p></p>]]>O militar norte-americano suspeito de ter matado 16 civis afegãos no domingo será julgado pela justiça militar dos Estados Unidos, anunciou esta segunda-feira o Pentágono./description>
```

Its possible remove the html tag '

' from description?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You would have to parse the CDATA section, however be aware that CDATA does not need to contain valid XML - that's the point of CDATA.

Comment: What the best way to parse this?! Read this section like a string!? Thanks

Comment: There's several ways. If I didnt' care for accuracy, and only cared about getting the image URL out, I might choose a Regular Expression. Alternatively, you could wrap it in some HTML and then try parsing it into a HTML DOM, then scanning for images.